# Передача данных из одного окна в другое. QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

Возникла такая проблема - не могу передать текст из `QLineEdit` в `QLabel`. Не знаю, почему, вроде все сделал правильно, но вот не работает.

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <form.h>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void sendData(QString str);
private slots:
    void onButtonSend();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Form *myform;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    myform = new Form;

    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), myform, SLOT(show()));

    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicled()), this, SLOT(onButtonSend()));

    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendData(QString)), myform, SLOT(recieveData(QSstring)));
}

void MainWindow::onButtonSend()
{
    emit sendData(ui->lineEdit->text());
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**form.h**

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Form();

private:
    Ui::Form *ui;

private slots:
    void recieveData(QString str);
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

**form.cpp**

```
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"

#include <QStringList>

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void Form::recieveData(QString str)
{
    QStringList lst = str.split(" ");
    if(lst.size() > 0) ui->label->setText(lst.at(0));
    if(lst.size() > 1) ui->label_2->setText(lst.at(1));
    if(lst.size() > 2) ui->label_3->setText(lst.at(2));
}


Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас опечатка в названии сигнала - во втором коннекте `clicled` вместо `clicked`. В консоли вывода приложения вам должно было об этом написать.

Если вы используете Qt5, рекомендую использовать "новый" синтаксис функции connect - на указателях на функцию. В этом случае ошибки будут определяться при компиляции, а не в рантайме.

Для преобразования "старого" синтаксиса в "новый" в креаторе можно встать на строку с функцией connect, нажать Alt+Enter и выбрать из всплывшего списка что-то типа "преобразовать в синтаксис Qt5"

Comment: новый синтаксис к сожалению иногда доставляет проблемы, так в случае с `QComboBox::currentIndexChanged` надо писать `static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged)`

Comment: Если не использовать новый, то старый нужно использовать только в виде: `bool isConnected = connect(...); Q_ASSERT(isConnected);`. Иначе подобные проблемы постоянно будут появляться.

Comment: @PavelGridin есть удобная функция для упрощения подобных записей - [`qOverload`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload).

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо. Переделал в mainwindow.cpp connect в новую форму, и высветилась ошибка что recieve data является приватным слотом. Соответственно перенес и private slots в publick, и все заработало! Вот собственно код.

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    myform = new Form;

    connect(ui->pushButton, &QAbstractButton::clicked, myform, &QWidget::show);

    connect(ui->pushButton, &QAbstractButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onButtonSend);

    connect(this, &MainWindow::sendData, myform, &Form::recieveData);
}

void MainWindow::onButtonSend()
{
    emit sendData(ui->lineEdit->text());
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**form.h**

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Form();
    void recieveData(QString str);

private:
    Ui::Form *ui;



};

#endif // FORM_H
```

Comment: Только вот теперь возник вопрос а как сделать что бы из 3 Lineedit разместить информацию в других Qlabel